# VSFTPD "Connection Refused" after changing listen_port

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vsftpd

I have just setup VSFTP on my Ubuntu 16.0.4 Virtual Machine.
When I type `ftp localhost` it connects fine, but if I add `listen_port = 44444` to the vsftpd.conf file and then run `ftp localhost` then I get "connection refused"

What could be causing this? Is there another setting I have to change?

[image: This is what I get once I run service vsftpd status]
This is what I get once I run service vsftpd status

Comment: Do you want vsftpd to listen to both ports 21 and 44444?

Comment: No only 44444 should be fine

Comment: Did you restart vsftp after the configuration change?

Comment: Yes I did restart vsftpd after adding in the listen_port = 44444

Comment: After you restart vsftpd, run `netstat -t -a -n | grep 44444`. Does it show anything?

Comment: Nope. Didn't show anything.

Comment: Does `ps aux | grep -i vsftpd` show anything?

Comment: Yup. It gives a bunch of information. Anything specific I should be looking for?

Comment: There should be exactly one line in the output that has `vsftpd` in the last column. Take the number from the second column of that line, the pid, and run `sudo lsof -p that_pid | grep LISTEN`. What ports does that show?

Comment: It gives 2 lines of output for me. Something like the following

"username 6488 0.2 0.9 662800 37076 ? sl 23:26 0:00 gedit /etc/vsftpd.conf"   
"username 6512 0.0 0.0 21292  1032 pts/2 s+ 23:38 0:00 grep --color=auto -i vsftpd"

Comment: I tried to do this on a different Ubuntu VM from scratch. I'm getting the same problems. Is there any other setting I have to change in the vsftpd.conf file to listen to another port?  I feel like I may be missing something

Comment: Neither of those lines shows a running vsftp daemon. Can you run `service vsftpd status` and add the output to your question? (remove your system name if that's sensitive information).

Comment: Edited the question and added the screenshot

Comment: According to the man page, `It is important to note that it is an error to put any space between the option, = and value.`. So vsftpd is likely giving up when it sees the line you added with the blanks around the `=`.

Answer (score 2):

When using a non default service port you need to specify it on the client. In your case it's still connecting to port 21 and failing.

One way to do it is:

```
ftp
open localhost 44444
```

Then run your commands interactively.

Comment: When I try to run the command you've given it gives the output as
ftp: connect: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  When you look at the status of the vsftpd service, it shows that you have an INVALIDARGUMENT.  In my case that was in the vsftpd config file; I had a typo where I typed a '-' instead of an '='.  I'd check your config file to make sure there are no errors, if no typos then maybe comment out any you added to narrow it down.